# libGDX - Google Play Game Services in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play-games

After migrating to Android Studio from Eclipse, I was struggling at best with it. Problem was that most guides and tutorials you could find are for Eclipse , but if you can find one for Android Studio, it is missing most important parts - implementing libraries or 3rd party code. After week of problems and errors here is a guide

Comment: No offense, but you should post the answer as a tutorial to your site, blog or somewhere else but not to SO like this.

Comment: I know it would be better, but i dont have a page. In the end if i save anyone a few hour with this it's ok

Answer (score 7):

Requirements: Google play services and Google Repostory (under Extras in SDK manager), [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

Firstly we need to add BaseGameUtils as Module:
[image]

then select Import Gradle Project and chose BaseGameUtil folder (do not copy BaseGameUtils in project before that step. Let Android Studio do that)
After gradle is done with syncing selefct Build > Make Module 'BaseGameUtils'
[image]

**NOTE** if u have uses-sdk:minSdkVersion error while build check this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334839/im-getting-error-basegameutilsprocessdebugandroidtestmanifest-on-android-s). Build :BaseGameUtils again after this

Last step for integranting BaseGameUtils is to include it into android module:
[image]
Sync project afterwards.

**NOTE** if you get uses-sdk:minSdkVersion error while build this will help - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718824/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller)

Now it's time to open your AndroidManifest file and include:

before *application* tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**NOTE:** there is no need to add google play dependencies in android gradle script becouse it is already included in BaseGameUtils

in *application*, before *activity*

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Now you need to set app_id number in Srtings (android/res/values/Strings.xml)

```
  <string name="app_id">928019648708</string>
```

Your app id is located in GooglePlay developer console under Game Services section (under game name)

For passing android native code to game code we will create ActionResolver interface in core module:

```
package com.mygame.test;

public interface ActionResolver {
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS();
    public void loginGPGS();
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score, String id);
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId);
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS();
    public void getAchievementsGPGS();
}
```

Now we need to make changes in AndroidLauncher class (check imports if you have problems):

```
package com.mygame.test.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.mygame.test.ActionResolver;
import com.mygame.test.MyGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver, GameHelper.GameHelperListener {

    private GameHelper gameHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (gameHelper == null) {
            gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
            gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
        }
        gameHelper.setup(this);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGame(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void loginGPGS() {
        if (!gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log in failed: " + ex.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        } else {
            gameHelper.reconnectClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score, String id) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id, score);
    }

   @Override
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
        Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
    }

    @Override
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkI5MyZk4FbHAJQXQ"), 100);
        } else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            loginGPGS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
        } else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            loginGPGS();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        gameHelper.getSignInError();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {

    }

    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    }
}
```

Create constructor in your main class (MyGame in this example):

```
public ActionResolver resolver;

public Base(ActionResolver ar) {
    resolver = ar;
}
```

to connect with gplay services call:

```
if (!resolver.getSignedInGPGS())
    resolver.loginGPGS();
```

unlock achievements and submit scores with:

```
if (resolver.getSignedInGPGS()){
    if (currentScore == 0){
        resolver.unlockAchievementGPGS("CgkI5MyZk4EbEAIQAg");
    }
    if (Cookie.bestScore >= 100){
        resolver.unlockAchievementGPGS("CgkI5MyZk4EbEAIQAw");
    }
    resolver.submitScoreGPGS(Cookie.bestScore, "CgkI5MyZk4EbEAIQAQ");
}
```

*note: use corresponding id valuses found in developer console for each achievement and for leaderbord*

and call leaderboards and achievements with

```
resolver.getLeaderboardGPGS();
resolver.getAchievementsGPGS();
```

Lastly desktop, ios and  html launcher can be resolved in the same way (example for desktop launcher)

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

    ActionResolver resolver= new ActionResolver() {
        @Override
        public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void loginGPGS() {
        }
        @Override
        public void submitScoreGPGS(int score, String id) {
        }
        @Override
        public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
        }
        @Override
        public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
        }
        @Override
        public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
        }
    };
    new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(resolver), config);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried to solve this issue a while back. All the tutorials were for Eclipse. Somehow I worked around that. This will help many in future. I followed the [official documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX) but it was very confusing as a newbie.

Comment: Np and i know. You literaly have to gather information for multiple sites and hope that it will work

Comment: You just forgot `@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }` in AndroidLauncher.