# I'm getting error: ":BaseGameUtils:processDebugAndroidTestManifest" on Android Studio startup only

Tags: android, google-play-services

My android app is using BaseGameUtils and every time I start Android Studio I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0] F:\Programowo\androidapps\FixMath\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

I'm getting this error only once on startup Android Studio.

That's how look my project structure
app project structure

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just add this line in BaseGameUtils AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>
```

on your `app --> manifest --> AndroidManifest.xml` file

That error means that the imported library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0` has a minSdkVersion specified as 7 whereas you seem to be targeting lower versions

Comment: my minSdkVersion is 14.

Comment: @Hype and BaseGameUtils?